# Simple Linqpad Linq join statement, select all fields

Tags: c#, linq, join, linqpad

I'm trying to do a simple join query in Linqpad, to mimic the following ...

```
SELECT *     
FROM Companies C    
JOIN Addresses A    
ON A.CompanyID = C.CompanyID    
WHERE C.CompanyID = 123
```

I'm using C# Expression (so no need to Dump, AFAIK), and tried the following unsuccessfully ...

```
from C in Companies    
join A in Addresses on C.CompanyID equals A.CompanyID    
where C.CompanyID = 123    
select C,A
```

So the result is `"name does not exist in current context"`

I suspect it might be because of common field in both tables, or the C,A syntax is basically wrong.

I want to be able to do the splat "*" across both tables. Is this possible?

Comment: if that is yolur actual LINQ code I can imagine why it is not work. Can you copy your LINQ code and show us your parentheses and such.

Comment: Did you misspell any of those member names in the class definition?

Comment: `Vicente` are you familiar with the 
`select new { construct..` for example 
`var results = select new { CompanyId= C.ID, Addresses = A.Address}`

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is, the following works ...

from C in Companies    
join A in Addresses on C.CompanyID equals A.CompanyID    
where C.CompanyID == 123    
select C

Comment: And the above is striaght, in linqpad, no parentheses, brackets, etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe your select should look like

```
select new { C, A }
```

or

```
select new { Company = C, Address = A }
```

as you are returning more than one complex object, so it should be wrapped with an anonymous type.  Or you can define your type and then set the properties like so

```
select new MyType { Company = C, Address = A }
```

Comment: I see. (I think! ) ok, that works, thanks very much! So returning one complex object, its simple, but more than one, you need to effectively create new object

Comment: @vicente correct, and the same applies to standard C# code.